# Upload file with application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: html

Is it possible to upload a file when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded?
i am following html code but it is only uploading/sending the formfields rather real uploading of the file.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="api/upload">
    <div>
        <label for="caption">Image Caption</label>
        <input name="caption" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="image1">Image File</label>
        <input name="image1" type="file" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you are posting the data to that URL `api/upload` directly or using JSON to post the form. In what language you are programming beside html?

Answer (score 1):

[According to W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4), you should use `multipart/form-data` when including a file in your submission.

Comment: Hi Mason, you are a right but i am trying to troubleshoot an issue here. The Website (not in my environment) is using  application/x-www-form-urlencoded for files upload and i was wondering if i can get simple html code to test.